# Getting supported AudioFormat list from AudioSystem

Tags: java, audioformat

I would like to be able to investigate the available `AudioFormat` types supported on a system with a view to selecting an appropriate one from a range of options, using preferred and fall-back values for frame rate and channels.

`AudioSystem` doesn't support directly querying supported audio formats, but I can get a list of available `SourceDataLine` from a `Mixer`.  And `SourceDataLine` inherits a `DataLine.Info` internal calls, which has a method to return the available formats: `getFormats ()`.

So my primary question is: **Is there a way to get an array of supported `AudioFormat` objects out of the Java audio system?**

Failing that: **Is there a way to get an array of supported `AudioFormat` objects out of a `Mixer`?**

And failing that: **Is it possible to get a `DataLine.Info` object from a `SourceDataLine` ?**

Ideally, I would like to do something *like* the following:

```
    public void exec () {
        Mixer.Info [] mixerInfoList = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo ();
        for (Mixer.Info mixerInfo : mixerInfoList) {
            System.out.println (mixerInfo.getDescription ());
            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer (mixerInfo);
            Line.Info [] lineInfoList = mixer.getSourceLineInfo ();
            for (Line.Info rawLineInfo : lineInfoList) {
                System.out.println ("  " + rawLineInfo.toString ());
                DataLine.Info lineInfo = (DataLine.Info) rawLineInfo;
                AudioFormat [] formats = lineInfo.getFormats ();
                for (AudioFormat fmt : formats) {
                    System.out.println ("    " + fmt.toString ());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this fails on the line `DataLine.Info lineInfo = (DataLine.Info) rawLineInfo;` because `rawLineInfo` is obviously an implementation-dependent object, not an instance of `DataLineInfo`.

It really is tremendously disappointing that `mixer.getSourceLineInfo ()` doesn't return an array of `DataLine.Info`.  There's no reason why it couldn't as the lines concerned are known with certainty to be implementations of `SourceDataLine` and therefore must support an `AudioFormat`.

Using the information provided by @gpasch (thanks heaps buddy) in the accepted answer, here's my final solution.  Function `isDesirable` identifies only audio formats I'm interested in.  Class `AudioFormatKey` is a wrapper that provides implementations of `equals()` for the `distinct()` transform, and `compareTo()` for the `sorted()` transform.

```
    public void exec () {
        System.out.println ("Available formats (stream):");
        Arrays.stream (AudioSystem.getSourceLineInfo (new Line.Info (SourceDataLine.class)))
                .filter (info -> info instanceof DataLine.Info)
                .map (info -> (DataLine.Info) info)
                .flatMap (dlinfo -> Arrays.stream (dlinfo.getFormats ()))
                .filter (this::isDesirable)
                .map (AudioFormatKey::new)
                .distinct ()
                .sorted ()
                .map (AudioFormatKey::getFormat)
                .forEach (format -> System.out.println ("  " + format));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this thing - it gets a list of formats in Windows. I don't know if all are supported or they work but it gives a list.

```
  public void getFormats() {
    Line.Info desired = new Line.Info( SourceDataLine.class );
    Line.Info[] info = AudioSystem.getSourceLineInfo( desired );
    for ( int i = 0;  i < info.length; ++i ) {
      System.out.println(i+" "+info[i].toString());
      if ( info[ i ] instanceof DataLine.Info ) {
        AudioFormat[] forms = ((DataLine.Info) info[i]).getFormats();
        for ( int n = 0;  n < forms.length;  ++n ) System.out.println( forms[ n ].toString() );
      }
    }
    desired = new Line.Info( TargetDataLine.class );
    info = AudioSystem.getTargetLineInfo( desired );
    for ( int i = 0;  i < info.length; ++i ) {
      System.out.println(i+" "+info[i].toString());
      if ( info[ i ] instanceof DataLine.Info ) {
        AudioFormat[] forms = ((DataLine.Info) info[i]).getFormats();
        for ( int n = 0;  n < forms.length;  ++n ) System.out.println( forms[ n ].toString() );
      }
    }
  }
```